# How can I detect that a menu is open in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm writing a JavaFX app and have a menubar with partial transparency.  When the user mouses over the menubar, it becomes fully opaque.  I'd also like it to be opaque when the user has opened one of the menus.  Is this possible somehow?  I'm using JavaFX 2 if it matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..!!

```
 menu.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event t)
        menubar.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent"); //
       // or you can use set opacity property
       menubar.setOpacity(0.25);
        }
    });
```

this event occurs when you show you menu...there also menu hidden propety..you can also use it.

Comment: Do you have full css for menubar.

Comment: Actually i want to change the color of Menu Item in menu bar so which css is helpful.

Comment: @JitendraKPareek yep but its not possible to put it here...you can asked question on other side and send me link here od question...i'll give you answer at there

Comment: `.menu-bar {
    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.MenuBarSkin";
    -fx-padding: 0.0em 0.666667em 0.0em 0.666667em; /* 0 8 0 8 */
    -fx-spacing: 0.166667em; /* 2 */
    -fx-base: derive(#d0d0d0,-70%);
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-color,50%), derive(-fx-color,-30%)), -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0, 0 ;
}
` try this its work fine